# matTooltip is not working with angular cli on mouse hover blinking Component

Tags: angular-material

I'm using Angular6 with angular-cli-6.0.8.
While using matTooltip then on mouse hover I'm getting the component(header) position change And mouseOut it's normal behaviour.
The following is the code:

```
<div #HeaderMenu>
    <div id="headerMenu" *ngIf="isHeaderButtonOpenStatus" style="display:block">
        <div class="right-h" *ngFor="let head of commonService.AllHeaderRoutingList">
            <a  [routerLink]="head.routerLink">
                <img class="addOnBtn" [id]="head.id" [src]="getSource(head)" [matTooltip]="head.title" (click)="setActive(head.id, head.source, head); toggleHeader()" />
            </a>
            <div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': head.isRouter ? '#0074BA' : '#232323' }" matTooltip="Pin to the top" (click)="setHeaderRouting(head)" class="isRouter"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So if you see in the above code on mouse hover on element `<a ...</a>and  <div [ngStyle]....</div>`

Totally `<div #HeaderMenu> ....</div>` is little bit shift from top to down.In other word creating blank space on top of the header(Please see the below image).
[on Mouse hover on Image button header Component position change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlZd5.png)

Please any help.

Answer (score -1):

Use `mdToolTip= "{{ your ngFor expression}}"`.